# applying svg image as texture to a mesh threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

am creating t-shirt customization using THREEJS and trying to create dynamic change of the particular design's color using svg image and update the t-shirt model in threejs. am stuck in updating the color of the svg image,looking for suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear where you're stuck, or why. Are you unable to change the color in the SVG? Are you unable to set the SVG as a texture? Are you unable to update the texture after you update the SVG? Are you getting any errors when you do any of these steps? HOW are you doing all if this (preferably share minimal code that replicates the problem)?

Comment: i have applied svg texture using 2D canvas to the mesh , post that unable to update the svg texture dynamically,

Comment: var img1 = new Image();
    var svg = document.getElementById("svgContainer").querySelector("svg");
    var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var svgSize = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvas.width = svgSize.width;
    canvas.height = svgSize.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

Comment: var material;   
    img1.src = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(svgData)}`;   
    img1.onload =  function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 32, 16);
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: texture
     });
        material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        init.scene.add(mesh);
        }

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Edit your question and share your code there.